# In Arkham Horror, can Shrivelling be used to compound bonuses?

Tags: arkham-horror

Probably the generic question is whether combat bonuses can be compounded at all or if it works like Eldritch Horror where '+' bonuses are only ever used for one item while re-rolls can be compounded. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, combat bonuses are cumulative as long as you do not exceed the 'hands' requirement. Shrivelling requires 1 hand so this rules out other two handed weapons or spells.

Skill bonuses such as Fight+1 will also come in to effect.